# Laravel 5.1 GET url parameter key not correct passing to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing, url-parameters

I have a problem with getting GET params from URL.

If I have e.g

```
http://domain.tld/route?page=2
```

And than in controller I dd data from GET with

```
dd(Input::all());
```

Laravel return is

```
array:1 [▼
  "//route?page" => "2"
]
```

But should be

```
array:1 [▼
  "page" => "2"
]
```

The problem exists on Laravel 5.1 on 5.0 there is all ok.

Route code is

```
Route::get('/klub', ['as' => 'teamInfo', 'uses' => 'Game\Team\TeamController@index']);
```

Contoller code is

```
final public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $userTeam = UserCache::get('team');
        if ($userTeam->id > 0)
            return view('game.team.info')->with(['userTeam' => $userTeam]);
        else {
            //this is executing in my case
            $proposals = Teams::proposals()->paginate(1);
            return view('game.team.empty', ['teamLimits' => conf('team.php'), 'userTeam' => $userTeam, 'proposals' => $proposals]);
        }
    }

var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
string(13) "//klub?page=2"

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
string(12) "/klub?page=2"
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using the Request object? `$request->input('page')`?

Comment: @Pitchinnate it's returning the same

Comment: Would need to see some more code then, like your router and function in controller might help.

Comment: @Pitchinnate I add direct code from my router and controller, I want to use pagination, and ?page is generated from paginator but not works, still first page is shown and paginator->currentPage() is returning 1 and I think this is this get parameter problem

Answer (score 2):

Something is corrupted in whatever server you're using (NGINX or Apache?). The server variables are passed through to PHP from the server engine and PHP can only parse what it's given.

You may have a bad URL rewrite in your `.htaccess` if you're using Apache or NGINX may be forwarding the value incorrectly. The `QUERY_STRING` should be `page=2`.

Comment: Right this is what I've added "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;"

Answer (score 0):

@dboskovic the problem was with nginx configuration, wrong variable passed to cgi, I now fix it and all works great.

Thanks so much for help and